# How to replace schema in jdbc url with java?

Tags: java

For example, a jdbc url like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/XXXX?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
```

How to replace `XXXX` with `test`.

Expected result is like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
```

***Note:*** `XXXX` is unknown, host ip:host `127.0.0.1:3306` is also unknown. In other words, these two strings are not fixed length.

And `?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8` is optional, it means the url maybe:

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/XXXX
```

then the result should be

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

***EDIT:*** 
As far as I know, regular expressions would save me, but I can't figure it out.

What I have tried:

```
"jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/xxxx?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8"
.replaceAll("[^/]+\\?", "test?");
```

but this doesn't work when the url is `jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/xxxx`.

Comment: you can use string replace

Comment: Parse the string into its constituent parts, and then put it back together, replacing the right part(s). Note that JDBC urls are driver specific, so a solution may not work on all drivers. I have voted to close as too broad, as you don't show any effort to solve this yourself.

Comment: I think you mean you only want to know for MySQL, because JDBC is an API for database access, and not MySQL specific.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel OK, U're right, sorry for my poor English. The `URL` is aimed to access `MySQL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a regex solution you could use this:

```
public class Requester {
  public static final String INPUT = 
      "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8";
  public static final String REPLACEMENT = "replacement";

  public static final Pattern REGEX = 
      Pattern.compile("(?<before>jdbc:mysql:\\/\\/[^:\\/]+(?::[0-9]+)?\\/)[^?]+(?<after>\\?.*)?");

  public static void main(final String... args) {
    Matcher m = REGEX.matcher(INPUT);

    if (!m.matches()) {
      throw new AssertionError("Bad URL");
    }
    final String before = m.group("before");
    final String after = m.group("after");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(before);
    sb.append(REPLACEMENT);
    if (after != null) {
      sb.append(after);
    }

    System.out.println(sb);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

XXX is the path of the uri. You can replace it like this.

```
String uriStr = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/XXXX?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8";
// this will result in mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/XXXX?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
String uriWithoutPrefixStr = uriStr.substring(5);
URI uri = URI.create(uriWithoutPrefixStr);
String newPath = "/test";
URI updatedUri = new URI(uri.getScheme(), uri.getUserInfo(), uri.getHost(), uri.getPort(), newPath, uri.getQuery(), uri.getFragment());
String backToJdbcFormat = "jdbc:" + updatedUri.toString();
System.out.println(backToJdbcFormat);
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a function as follows:

```
public String getUrl(String ipAndPort, String dbName, String... optionals){

        if (ipAndPort == null || dbName == null)
            return null;
        if (ipAndPort.isEmpty() || dbName.isEmpty())
            return null;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("jdbc:mysql://");
        sb
            .append(ipAndPort)
            .append("/")
            .append(dbName);

        if (optionals.length > 0)
            sb.append("?");

        for (int i=0;i<optionals.length;i=i+2){
            if (i>0)
                sb.append("&");
            sb
                .append(optionals[i])
                .append("=")
                .append(optionals[i+1]);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick :)

```
String original = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/XXXX?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8";
String xxxx = original.split("3306/")[1].split("\\?useUnicode")[0];
String updated = xxxx.replaceAll(xxxx,"test");
```

It only assumes that the url contains "3306/" and "?useUnicode" :)

Comment: Thanks for your advice and upvote, but port number is unknown. `?useUnicode` is also optional.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method that extracts the db name and then just replace it, something like this:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class JdbcUrl {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/XXXX?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8";
        String updatedUrl = jdbcUrl.replace(getDatabaseName(jdbcUrl), "YYYY");

        System.out.println(jdbcUrl);
        System.out.println(updatedUrl);
    }

    public static String getDatabaseName(String conStr) throws MalformedURLException {
        URL url = new URL("http" + conStr.substring(conStr.indexOf("://")));
        String dbName = url.getPath();

        while (dbName.startsWith("/")) {
            dbName = dbName.substring(1);
        }

        return dbName;
    }
}
```

output:

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/XXXX?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/YYYY?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another regex:

```
originalUrl.replaceAll("\\w+\\?", "test?");
```

Try it at https://regexr.com/51hap